# C#/BinaryWriter: Weird Characters apprearing in Output Stream

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am having difficulties figuring out what is causing wierd characters to appear in my output stream ... full code **[@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/c3hKqx71)**

**Fiddler output**

notice the "`s`", "`X`", "`�`" before my boundary?

```
s---------------634227387532666996
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='key'

c06f4d0cdf6f2cc652635a08be34973d
X---------------634227387532666996
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='type'

file
�---------------634227387532666996
Content-Disposition: form-data; name='image'; filename='application_osx_split.png'
Content-Type=image/png

�PNG
```

**my code**

```
var bound = "-------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
var tmplField = "--" + bound + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name='{0}'\r\n\r\n{1}\r\n";
var tmplFile = "--" + bound + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name='{0}'; filename='{1}'\r\nContent-Type={2}\r\n\r\n";

....

using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    var reqWriter = new BinaryWriter(reqStream);

    reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplField, "key", "c06f4d0cdf6f2cc652635a08be34973d"));
    reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplField, "type", "file"));
    reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplFile, "image", Path.GetFileName(filepath), "image/" + Path.GetExtension(filepath).Substring(1)));
    reqWriter.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
    reqWriter.Write("\r\n--" + bound + "--");
    reqWriter.Flush();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that if i did something like below instead, using a combination of Stream & Binary Writers, I can avoid the problem. Why is this so?

```
var reqWriter = new StreamWriter(reqStream);
reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplField, "key", "c06f4d0cdf6f2cc652635a08be34973d"));
reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplField, "type", "file"));
reqWriter.Write(string.Format(tmplFile, "image", Path.GetFileName(filepath), "image/" + Path.GetExtension(filepath).Substring(1)));
reqWriter.Flush();

var binWriter = new BinaryWriter(reqStream);
binWriter.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));
binWriter.Write("\r\n--" + bound + "--");
binWriter.Flush();
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using WebClient but HttpWebRequest?

Comment: WebClient.UploadFile does multipart/form-data, but allows only one file at a time and doesn't support additional fields at the same time. But you can build the payload yourself and then set the right content type and use WebClient.UploadData or WebClient.UploadString. WebClient supports non-blocking operations in the form of it's XxxAsync methods. It's much more convenient than HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BinaryWriter prefixes strings with their length.

Use a StreamWriter instead.

Comment: Oh, then can I use a `StreamWriter` to write `byte[]` too? Look at the `File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)` part, thats the only reason why I used `BinaryWriter` later on when I discovered `StreamWriter` can;t write `byte[]`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't note the byte[]. In this case you need to convert the strings to byte[] using UTF8Encoding and write the byte[] directly to the stream.

Comment: Alternatively, you can (or maybe even need to?) encode the file contents as Base64. The result is a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853803/is-there-a-popular-c-library-for-working-http-eg-simplifing-working-with-httpwe/1853909#1853909

Comment: what if I don't need to convert to base64 how do I use a normal `StreamWriter` to write `byte[]`

Comment: by the way, if I did the base64 encoding, will my image be `image/png` or something else? I think my request is marked in red in fiddler means something wrong with the request headers etc.