# Easy alternative to HttpWebRequest for POST requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to trigger an action on a remote server using an http `POST` request. The server sends a response, either `Y` or `N`, to inform me if the action suceeded or not.

I am looking at using `HttpWebRequest` to do this, but this seems too complex. To use this class you have to set all the headers, such as content type and content length.

Is there a quicker way to send a `POST` request that doesn't require setting lower level properties such as this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this *[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx)*

```
 // Create a new WebClient instance.
 WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
 byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData("YOUR URI","POST","DATA to be Posted");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class. It's much more simpler and it's basically a *wrapper* for `HttpWebRequest`. It encapsulate all this complex logic you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest built in class in the framework is [WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853909/66849). Scott Hanselman has [an example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx) on how to perform gets and posts using it. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853909/66849) also has a good overview on how to post data.

If you have control over the server you're posting to, you might want to consider making it respond with [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) instead of some custom method.

Answer (score 0):

the wcf web api project has an http client. It's super easy to use. http://wcf.codeplex.com/